# Aqua Data Studio Server Registration Scripts

Tags: database, sql-scripts, aquafold

I am trying to run a startup script in Aqua Data Studio when a user logs in to any database. I understand that the process for this is to go to Script in the Server Registration box and write the SQL scripts/queries you would want to run when connected. I tried to retrieve the count of a small table (2 rows), but I cannot see the results anywhere when I connect to it and open a new Query Analyzer window. Is there a specific place where I can view these results that is not immediately apparent? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scripts tab in the Server Properties, is more suited for SQL to change the Database or Schema. For e.g. For MSSQL Server, if your default database in the Server Connection is MASTER and you want to change to a database named NORTHWIND, you would need to enter USE NORTHWIND in the Scripts tab. It is not suited to run queries and view the results. This is useful if you want to perform some  initialization. One thing you can look for is the FluidShell. See link [here](http://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation15/page/246/FluidShell). 
In server properties, next to the "Script" tab, there is a tab called "FluidShell". If you enter your startup script there and then launch FluidShell (by right clicking on your registered server > FluidShell), you'll see the script being executed and its output displayed.

Comment: I posted the same question on the Aqua Data Studio Forum and got the same answer. Would've answered it myself, but had no time. Thanks for this anyways! :)